# error: illegal character in xamarin app

Tags: android, c#, xamarin

При попытке скомпилить приложение в Debug mode выдает подобную ошибку

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_71\\bin\javac.exe -J-Dfile.encoding=UTF8 -d obj\Debug\android\bin\classes -classpath "C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v6.0\mono.android.jar;C:\Users\nemes\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Android.Support.v4\23.0.1.3\embedded\classes.jar;C:\Users\nemes\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Android.Support.v4\23.0.1.3\embedded\libs\internal_impl-23.0.1.jar;C:\Users\nemes\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Android.Support.v7.AppCompat\23.0.1.3\embedded\classes.jar;C:\Users\nemes\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Android.Support.v7.MediaRouter\23.0.1.3\embedded\classes.jar;C:\Users\nemes\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Android.Support.v7.MediaRouter\23.0.1.3\embedded\libs\internal_impl-23.0.1.jar;C:\Users\nemes\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Android.Support.v7.RecyclerView\23.0.1.3\embedded\classes.jar;C:\Users\nemes\AppData\Local\Xamarin\GooglePlayServices.Base\8.1.0\embedded\classes.jar;C:\Users\nemes\AppData\Local\Xamarin\GooglePlayServices.Basement\8.1.0\embedded\classes.jar;C:\Users\nemes\AppData\Local\Xamarin\GooglePlayServices.Maps\8.1.0\embedded\classes.jar" -bootclasspath C:\Users\nemes\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\platforms\android-23\android.jar -encoding UTF-8 "@C:\Users\nemes\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp4C9E.tmp" 

    obj\Debug\android\src\com\companyname\murakami_kiev\R.java:1: error: illegal character: \0
```

Читал на основном СО , что проблема в кодировке файла, но насколько я понимаю R.java генерится автоматически.
Как это можно пофиксить?

При запуске в Release mode все нормально и приложение стартует на телефоне

Answer (score 3):

Проблему решил.

Просто выпилил файл R.java и скомпилил еще раз